# "Splistitem being updated was not retrieved with all taxonomy fields" in GUI?

Tags: 2013, taxonomy

I often get this message when I use a column that is a taxonomy field. Sometimes it works if the list is empty and I re-apply my custom created content type, but sometimes it doesn't. 
Anyone have any suggestions? This happens in SharePoint GUI.

I should clarify that I get the message when I try to save an item.

Comment: I don't think it's a throttling issue since I only use one taxonomy field.

Answer (score 0):

IF everything has been setup properly:

- Added an extra note field to the schema.xml for each Taxonomy field
- Changed the throttling settings

AND everything stated in this article is clear and okey-dokey:

http://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/fix-the-splistitem-being-updated-was-not-retrieved-with-all-taxonomy-fields/

then I would suggest to check this:

- open site collection content type using SharePoint Web Interface:
- site settings
- site content types
- open the content type
- In the Columns list open the column giving the error
- Modify site column
- Edit the term set column setting
- save

Comment: Great answer. Saving the columns did the trick for me